# Style issues due to Sap Fiori 2.0 update

Tags: sap-fiori, sapui5

I have some style issues with the SAP Fiori 2.0 upgrade.

In the new version, the `sap_bluecrystal` style theme has been deprecated, and has been replaced with `sap_belize`. In our Fiori applications some style is not showing good since the upgrade and we need to revise it.

Is there a way to migrate the old `sap_bluecrystal` styles to the new ones?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you describe the problem in more detail. Screenshots would be nice.
Maybe the issue is something that can be solved differently.

Otherwise we see 4 options:

1. Use bluecrystal, that, despite being deprecated, is still available.
2. Use belize
3. Create your own style on top of bluecrystal using the Theme Designer
4. Create your own style on top of belize using the Theme Designer

We generally recommend option 2.
If this is not feasible, you might go for option 4 and adapt belize to your liking.

For Theme Designer, please see the following links:

[UI Theme Designer](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/theme_designer/frameset.htm)

[Help Portal UI Theme Designer](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/a1/18094264684230bb6510045b5b5b7c/content.htm)

[Create and Apply Custom Theme to SAPUI5 Application](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/09/19/create-and-apply-custom-theme-to-sapui5-application/)